# How to make an 0$ transaction to get information from users?

Tags: php, payment-processing

How can I use Adyen to make a 0$ transaction to save the users information, a recurring contract so to speak. I can only do transactions that aren't 0$.

Whenever I do a transaction of 0$, go to the page, click a payment option. I get the error: `Error: Invalid Amount Specified`.

What I need is: Save users payment information i.e creditcard info in Adyen. Use these payment details to send a payment on a different time.

Comment: if you need to save users details if he/ she choose 0$ transaction. you can simply save the required information without redirecting to payment service.is that helpful?

Comment: How am I able to get his payment details if they aren't redirected to the payment service? What I need is: Save users payment information i.e creditcard info in Adyen. Use these payment details to send a payment on a different time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on their website:

> To make 0$ transactions with Adyen for a recurring contract, you’ll have to contact Adyen with your Company ID. You need to be whitelisted to do this.